# Why does the mother cat do this?

Tags: cats, breeding, feral

A stray mother cat just had two baby kittens in our apartment complex.  They can't stand or walk or meow yet. They live in the staircase. I've visited them several times to give the mother cat milk. All three are usually snuggled up but when the mother cat sees me, she runs after me.  Why is this? Is she trying to protect the babies by chasing me away? Or does she want food? The cat doesn't hiss, just meows and follows me. And tries to lick my toe.

Btw, there is no SPCA here, and the kittens are warm because it's summer and the nights are hot. Also the kittens are drinking breast milk. Anything else I can do to make them more comfortable?

Comment: Does the mother cat let you touch her? It's possible she's tame and sees you as an ally. Also, what kind of milk are you giving her? Most cats don't do well with milk once they're weaned. If she's tame and lets you touch her and the kittens, you may be able to adopt her/the kittens.

Comment: @Littleblackdog yes Kate was right. I have a cat that I adopted after feeding her while she's a stray near the staircase at my apartment, with her newborn kitten. Everyday when I reach home from school, she will always wait at the stairsway, chasing after and meowing at me; which I assumed she's asking for food. I fed her and she allows me to touch her and play with her kitten (she had only 1 kitten). Thereafter, I adopted her while her kitten was taken away (hopefully by the SPCA).

Answer (score 4):

A cat meows for basic communication. If it was attacking it would probably hiss and arch its back. Sounds like she has learned you mean milk. But if the cat does not seem to have any owners, I would suggest trying to get all 3 of the kittens and take them to a no-kill shelter after they get a bit older. Also you could adopt them yourself - if this was the case, then take them to a vet first to have them examined.

Answer (score 0):

My only comment is that milk, at least cow's milk, actually is not a good food for cats.

Many cats have lactose problems and can't fully digest it. This can lead to diarrhea or vomitting and, besides, it simply is not a balanced diet. If you are going to feed her, buy some brand dry food for her.

As to making them more comfortable, it sounds like mom is doing a quite satisfactory job with her children.